# Adding a year to date in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have two `DateTimePicker` controls on a form.

How can I automatically add a year to the date I have selected in the 1st `DateTimePicker` and display it on the 2nd `DateTimePicker`? For example, if select a date `09/22/2017`, then I want the 2nd `DateTimePicker` to display `09/22/2018`.

Is this possible? If so, would you suggest some appropriate code? If not, would you suggest an alternative way to do it?

[image]

Comment: [AddYears](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Frustrated  :-)

Comment: ...and the reasons for the silent downvotes, people? That's just plain rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, using the `DateTimePicker`'s `ValueChanged` event:

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(Sender As DateTimePicker, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
  Me.DateTimePicker2.Value = Sender.Value.AddYears(1)
End Sub
```

To automatically generate this event handler code, double-click the first `DateTimePicker` control on your form.

You'll notice in this example that I've changed the casting of `Sender` from `Object` to `DateTimePicker`, so we can get IntelliSense in the IDE.

Comment: Whoah! It worked! :D Great thanks! I have one more question, what if the input is "09/22/2017" and the output is "09/23/2018"?

Comment: @FrustratedProgrammer — I'm not sure I follow you. `Date.Parse("09/22/2017").AddYears(1)` will always equal `9/22/2018`. Are you saying that `9/23/2018` is your desired result? If so use `Date.Parse("09/22/2017").AddYears(1).AddDays(1)`.

Comment: Oh! Thank you very much! You are a great help! :) I already changed it and it worked perfectly! :)

Comment: @FrustratedProgrammer — You're welcome, glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you need to do and what YEAR you're looking for, but the simple answer is:

SomeComboBox.text = Now.Year

Comment: What I mean is, if I input a certain date, like for example, "09/22/2017" then I want that after clicking the first datetime picker (Sorry I did call it a combo box earlier.) then it will automatically display this to the next date time picker.. "09/22/2018"

Answer (score 0):

If you are selecting a date then take the year from the datepicker.
Append it to the textbox below.

You can do it in this way.

```
year = dtp1.Value.Year
tb.Text = tb.text + year
```

This will just append the year when you change the datepicker however if you want tb.Text year to be replaced on every click of datepicker then you should do something like this.

```
Dim str as String  = tb.Text        'Save current text
Dim arr as String() = str.Split(",")'Get previous text
currentYear = dtp1.Value.Year       'Get current year
tb.Text = arr(0) + currentYear      'Replace year in textbox with new year
```

Comment: What I mean is, if I input a certain date, like for example, "09/22/2017" then I want that after clicking the first datetime picker (Sorry I did call it a combo box earlier.) then it will automatically display this to the next date time picker.. "09/22/2018"

Comment: Public Class Form1
    Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged
        Label1.Text = DateTimePicker1.Value.Year + 1
        DateTimePicker2.Value = Now.Day & "-" & Now.Month & "-" & Label1.Text
    End Sub
End Class

Comment: Copy the above code and run in your vs ide. It should work as you expected. Changes the year of next dtp when you change the value of first dtp.